# In python/pandas, how can I create a program to 'auto-name' dataframes from the titles of the .csv files in any given directory?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It seems fairly routine if multiple input .csv files are present to create a list of dataframes and then 'manually' assign them names. I want to know if it is possible to create a program that will accept any path as an input and automate creating and naming the dataframes based on the names of the .csv files in the directory. I would be satisfied with the dataframes being assigned the same names as the .csv (minus the extension)

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
import numpy as np
```

path entered by user

```
path = 'C:/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/datasets/world_bank_data/'
```

get list of names from .csv. to be used to label data frame

```
filenames = glob.glob(path + '/*.csv')
names = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(path + '/*.csv')]
names = np.char.replace(names, '.csv', '')
names = list(names)
```

```
>>names
Out[146]: ['Country-Series', 'Country', 'Data', 'FootNote', 'Series-Time', 'Series']
```

The above code can be re-used with the user entering the desired path. To 'manually' rename, I could do:

```
dataframes = []

for filename in filenames:
    dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(filename))      

[df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6] = dataframes
```

**HOWEVER**, I want to use the names in the (changeable) list generated above to name the dataframes.
I'm hopeful there is an obvious and simple solution for this!? :)

Thanks!

Comment: I would avoid using specific variable names, instead, you can make a dictionary of dataframes, you can use the file names as keys. If you really want to assign variable names, you have to modify `globals()`

Comment: Thanks! I created a dictionary and used print statements for the user to view the keys :)